# show error message if user try to go to link directly with out logged in

Tags: php

I am trying to show error message if user try to go to link directly with out logged in.

For example:here is my URL: www.xxxx.com/custom/login.php

when user used this URL they will redirect to my custom portal.

and i have another URL like www.xxx.com so it will take them to another portal.

So now what i did in my custom portal is i gave one button called upload in dashboard for admin once they logged in if they click on the button they will redirect to www.xxx.com.

Here is my button code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <?php
                if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') {
                    ?>
                    <li   style="border-left: 7pt solid #B1B3B3;padding: 0px;" ><a  href="../">Upload </a>
            <?php
                }
                ?>


            </ul>
```

so what i am trying to do is if they try to remove the custom/login.php from URL and try to access the www.xxx.com i want to show some error message

if they try to go from dashboard i don't want to restrict them.

Can anyone help me how to do that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass the query string in url

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use query string on url

```
<li   style="border-left: 7pt solid #B1B3B3;padding: 0px;" ><a  href="../?admin_key=<?php echo base64_encode('zxcvbnm') ?>">Upload </a>
```

Now on the index page of www.xxxx.com you have to check

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['admin_key']))
{

    // now decode the key

    $decode_key = base64_decode($_GET['admin_key']);

    // then match the key 

    if($decode_key == 'zxcvbnm')
    {

        // run the page content here
    }
    else
    {
        // show error
    }
}
else
{
    // show error
}

?>
```